# diagonal subalgebras of classical Lie algebras

Tags: lie-algebras

How to use the Invariance Lemma to prove that the diagonal subalgebra of classical Lie algebras are self-normalizing? When $\operatorname{char}\ F=0$?

---

(Invariance Lemma)
Assume that $F$ has characteristic zero. Let $L$ be a Lie subalgebra of $gl(V )$ and let $A$ be an ideal of $L$. Let $λ : A → F$ be a weight of $A$. The associated weight space $V_λ = \{v ∈ V : av = λ(a)v,\ \forall a ∈ A\}$ is an L-invariant subspace of $V$.

Comment: What is the "Invariance Lemma" ? I just would use that every CSA is self-normalizing, and these diagonal subalgebras of classical Lie algebras are just CSA's.

Comment: Yes, I agree. But actually this question is to see an application of the   Invariance Lemma which I will insert it under the question

Comment: @DietrichBurde Sorry, but what do you mean by *CSA*? I’m quite puzzled with this abbreviation. (I have just covered the first two chapters of Humphrey’s book.) Thank you!

Comment: Usually a CSA is a Cartan subalgebra. Humphrey's says this in his book, I think.